# Как кнопке button обеспечить возможность запуск одновременно двух вычислений, в двух разных скриптах

Tags: javascript, jquery, скрипт

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно прописать код кнопке button, что бы она при одном нажатии запускала бы одновременно два разных вычисления (в разных jquery скриптах) по разным id (как пример один #qty а второй #qty2). Кнопка на данный момент имеет такой вид:

```
<button onclick="qplus('#qty');">
```

Буду благодарен, если кто поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляй обработчики через `addEventListener`.

Comment: Это всё равно будет не одновременно :)

Comment: Думаю, автора такая "неодновременность" устроит ;)